# Why is SVP not in coNP if Gram Schmidt Orthogonalization can provide us with a lower bound of the shortest vector

Tags: lattice

From https://cbright.myweb.cs.uwindsor.ca/reports/cs667proj.pdf

> More precisely, the decision version of the poly(n)-unique SVP problem lies in NP and coNP. This means
> that given a lattice and a target bound d there is a short certificate which proves that the shortest vector
> is either shorter than d or longer than d. In the former case, the certificate is simply the shortest vector
> itself. In the latter case, the certificate is a basis of the lattice in which every vector in the Gram–Schmidt
> orthogonalization of the basis is longer than d.

It seems like we can use this logic to deduce that SVP is also in coNP. Since we know that the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of the basis gives us a lower bound of the shortest vector.

It seems like we can provide a certificate that is the basis of the lattice and its Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization will be able to answer the no instance of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not imply that SVP is in coNP without a proof that a basis with the necessary properties (all its GS norms are larger than $d$) actually exists.